# Spring Quartz Scheduler Service requires to run only on a single node instead of all nodes

Tags: java, spring, quartz-scheduler

There is an spring web application - Yevi. Yevi is deployed in a clustered environment having 6 nodes. All nodes using a shared Yevi deployment package. Application has following configuration in applicationContext.xml:

```
<bean id="cronYeviTrigger" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerBean">
      <property name="jobDetail" ref="YeviJob"/>
        <!-- run every morning at 6 AM  -->
        <property name="cronExpression" value="0 0 6 * * ?"/>
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">
      <property name="triggers">
        <list>
          <ref bean="YeviTrigger"/>
        </list>
      </property>
      <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:quartz.properties"/>
    </bean>
```

And, quartz.properties has nothing right now. The above CRON Job is designed to run at 6 AM everyday and perform some business operation and sleep back once the business operation gets done. And, awake again at same time and perform the same business operations.

The problem, I believe, is related to clustered environment. Once all nodes get up and running. 6 CRON Jobs created - one on each node and the desire business operation performs 6 times instead of just once in a day.

I think, there must be some sort of configuration required to do run this only once on a single node instead of running it all nodes. I need it to run this CRON Job at 6 AM only one node and if that node is done then on fail-over it should check the next node and run the CRON Job there.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

With JDBC JobStore you can achieve trigger firing by exactly one node.

http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.2.x/configuration/ConfigJDBCJobStoreClustering

**EDIT**

> Clustering currently only works with the JDBC-Jobstore (JobStoreTX or JobStoreCMT), and essentially works by having each node of the cluster share the same database.
>
> Load-balancing occurs automatically, with each node of the cluster firing jobs as quickly as it can. When a trigger’s firing time occurs, the first node to acquire it (by placing a lock on it) is the node that will fire it.
>
> Only one node will fire the job for each firing. What I mean by that is, if the job has a repeating trigger that tells it to fire every 10 seconds, then at 12:00:00 exactly one node will run the job, and at 12:00:10 exactly one node will run the job, etc. It won’t necessarily be the same node each time - it will more or less be random which node runs it. The load balancing mechanism is near-random for busy schedulers (lots of triggers) but favors the same node for non-busy (e.g. few triggers) schedulers.

Comment: follow this link : http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.2.2/configuration/ConfigJDBCJobStoreClustering.html

Answer (score 0):

I have to admin I spent a long time faffing with Quartz with this problem before realizing that creating a new Thread with

```
while (true) {
    doThing();
    sleep(TIME_GAP)
}
```

Was a far simpler solution for running jobs on each node.

remember to make the thread a deamon thread so it doesnt prevent shutdown of the JVM